# Calendar issue, doesn't save the date

Tags: java, android, calendar

So I was writing some code to save the time spent on a wifi network. I'm almost there except the time isn't getting saved correctly.

This object receives a broadcast, after which it checks if it's connected to a wifi AP. It  gets a Date object with the moment of connection. After the disconnect it gets the Date of when the connection was interrupted.

However when it logs the start and stop date it always seems to get the current date, also for the start object:

```
private Date startDate;
private Date stopDate;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (isOnline(context)) {
        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        android.net.wifi.WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager
                .getConnectionInfo();
        Log.d("WIFI:", "IN FIRST IF, SO CONNECTED");
        if (wifiInfo.getSupplicantState() == (SupplicantState.COMPLETED)) {
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            this.startDate = c.getTime();
            this.initialConnection = true;
        }
    } else if (this.initialConnection) {
        Calendar d = Calendar.getInstance();
        this.stopDate = d.getTime();
        //problem persists here
        String s = "TIME:" + d.getTime().toString() + " started at:"
                + startDate.toString() + "stopped at"
                + this.stopDate.toString();
        Log.d("WIFI:", s);
        this.initialConnection = false;
    }
}
```

Output

```
D/WIFI:   (  684): TIME:Mon Mar 12 13:18:16 GMT+02:00 2012 started at:Mon Mar 12 13:18:16 GMT+02:00 2012stopped atMon Mar 12 13:18:16 GMT+02:00 2012
```

Is my startTime getting the current time again when it is referred to? How can I make it save the startTime?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find anything wrong with your use of Calendar. The following SSCCE has correct behaviour. There must be a problem with the logic in onReceive(). Perhaps the first half is being called again causing the startDate to be updated to the current time.

```
public class CalendarTest {
    private Date stopDate;
    private Date startDate;

    public void online() {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        this.startDate = c.getTime();
    }

    public void offline() {
        Calendar d = Calendar.getInstance();
        this.stopDate = d.getTime();
        String s = "TIME:" + d.getTime().toString() + "\nstarted at:"
                + startDate.toString() + "\nstopped at"
                + this.stopDate.toString();
        System.out.println(s);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CalendarTest test = new CalendarTest();
        test.online();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        test.offline();
    }
}
```

Output

```
TIME:Mon Mar 12 12:29:04 GMT 2012
started at:Mon Mar 12 12:29:01 GMT 2012
stopped atMon Mar 12 12:29:04 GMT 2012
```